# Printing wrong type for hash value on C

Tags: c, hash, cryptography, openssl, sha1

I'm heaving a problem on printing a hash generated with OpenSSL, code (using OpenSSL):

```
char *computeHash(char *msg){
    static char hs[20];

    SHA1(msg, strlen(msg), hs);
    return hs;
}

int main(){
    char *text;
    char *hash;
    int i;

    text = "test";
    hash = computeHash(text);

    for(i=0;i<20;i++){
        printf("%02x",hash[i]);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

As returning I'm getting:

```
$ ./a.out ffffffa94affffff8fffffffe5ffffffccffffffb1ffffff9bffffffa61c4c0873ffffffd3ffffff91ffffffe9ffffff87ffffff982fffffffbbffffffd3
```

Is that any way to print it right?

Thanks,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `%02x` format string is for an integer. But you are printing a character. Also, `hash` is a `char *` pointer, you probably want an `unsigned char *`. How about:

```
unsigned char *hash_ptr = (unsigned char *) hash;
for(i=0;i<20;i++){
    printf("%02x", (int) hash_ptr[i]);
}
```

Comment: David, aren't single unsigned chars pushed as `int` via promotion based on the variadic nature of `printf()`? I only ask because I have done similar and it has worked in the past without the cast. I've no reason to doubt I was lucky, just curious. (and +1).

Comment: @WhozCraig Yes, which is why his code didn't work. It was that promotion that failed. He would have been in trouble either way. :)

Comment: I can see it breaking horridly extended the sign-bit of a `char` through to an `int`, to be sure (and his output seems to demonstrate that nicely). I was just making sure I was *not* just lucky that `unsigned char` didn't need the cast. It shouldn't since it value-promotes into `int` as-is. Just checked, and it still works, so at least i know i wasn't hallucinating.